# Unable to monitor Cisco route tables with SolarWinds

Tags: cisco, routing, monitoring

I recently switched from scanning a linux-router based network hosted on CORE emulation software, to scanning Cisco IOS routers hosted on a GNS3 emulation with SolarWinds.

Everything seems the same, except that the routing info isn't imported from the Cisco devices. When I look in the Network tab of Node Details for any of my Cisco routers, they all say "No poll has been done yet," even though I've polled for and can view other (interface, ip, etc) information about the nodes.

Any reason why this might be the case? Are Cisco route tables incompatible with SolarWinds? Do I need to enable something somewhere?

When I go into a node's details and click on "List Resources" at the top, I do see Routing, Routing table, and OSPF neighbors selected, they just aren't polled for when I poll the node.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me you're not running an actual production network off a GNS3 based router..

Comment: Haha no, we're testing some integration with SolarWinds on a lab environment as we don't have access to the physical network yet.